# default namespace scope warning (1084) in Flex script file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have an MXML file, which references an external script file for all its event handlers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script source="LoginExample.as" />
    <mx:Button id="btnGoodLogin" click="btnGoodLogin_onClick()"  label="Good Login" enabled="true" y="28"/>
    <mx:Button id="btnBadLogin" click="btnBadLogin_onClick()"  label="Bad Login" enabled="true" y="28" x="112"/>
    <mx:Button id="btnLogout" click="btnLogout_onClick()"  label="Logout" enabled="true" y="28" x="219"/>
    <mx:Button id="btnCheck" click="btnCheck_onClick()"  label="Check" enabled="true" y="28" x="325"/>
    <mx:Text id="txtResult"  y="58" width="263"/>
</mx:Application>
```

The external file defines the handlers:

```
// LoginExample.as
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
function btnGoodLogin_onClick():void
{
   // ...
}
function btnBadLogin_onClick():void
{
  // ...
}
// etc. for other handlers
```

Every single one of these handlers, plus every other function defined in the script, results in a warning message from the compiler:

> 1084: function 'btnBadLogin_onClick'
>   will be scoped to the default
>   namespace: LoginExample: internal.  It
>   will not be visible outside of this
>   package.  LoginExample/src    LoginExample.as line
>   27    1225162212118   189

What's the best way to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stick a `private`, `protected`, `internal` or `public` before the function declaration:

```
private function btnBadLogin_onClick():void
```

That should do the trick.